# Sinatra Rack Test "0 Tests" run

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, sinatra, rack-test

I'm trying to get some unit tests written for a small Sinatra app.  When I run `ruby test.rb`, the terminal reports that it is "running tests" but it is not actually picking up my unit tests.

The app itself runs fine whether by locally typing `ruby app.js` or through phusion passenger, so hopefully that indicates that my config.ru and app.js file are set up properly.

Here is what I have so far.

**test.rb**

```
require_relative 'app'
require 'test/unit'
require 'rack/test'

ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'

class AppTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  puts "Debug 1"
  def app
    puts "Debug 2"
    Sinatra::Application
  end

  def root
    get '/'
    assert last_response.ok?
  end
end
```

**The terminal**

```
$ ruby test.rb
Debug 1
Run options: 

# Running tests:

Finished tests in 0.004781s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

It seems as though "app" and the first test "root" are never being run, since the debug line isn't printed.  What have I missed in the test setup?  It looks as though I'm mimicking tests from the sinatra recipe / existing apps so I'm not sure what I'm messing up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test method has to be named `test_root` for the test to be run. Otherwise it's just a private method and won't be called unless it's called by an `test_` method.